# I need to load driver for Epson Perfection 4180 Scanner

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

The scanner doesn't seem to have an easy to load driver that I can get at the Epson site.  The options that are available seem to need to be installed at the terminal prompt.  I am lost at that point. 
The files that are available for download are:

```
Perfection 4180…
    Scanner Driver  Linux
    latest  for gcc 3.2/3.3     All language
    12-21-2011  
Perfection 4180…
    Scanner Driver  Linux
    latest  for gcc 3.4 or later    All language
    12-21-2011  
Perfection 4180…
    Scanner Driver  Linux
    latest  iscan plugin package for gcc 3.2/3.3    All language
    12-21-2011  
Perfection 4180…
    Scanner Driver  Linux
    latest  iscan plugin package for gcc 3.4 or later   All language
    12-21-2011
```

I am confused on which of these files I need.

Answer (score 0):

None of those will work. They are only offering Fedora/RedHat drivers and tar.gx binaries. Thus you are not provided a driver you can install correctly from that website.

Please direct your complaints to Epson for the disgraceful way they are treating Ubuntu users by not providing drivers.